# Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Tags: r, closures, mode, coerce

```
library(dplyr)

dend1 <- df %>% 
 dist %>% 
 hclust("complete") %>% 
 as.dendrogram
```

> Error in as.vector(x, mode) :
> cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Why is this error popping out? Thanks

I have tried multiple ways but couldn't manage to solve the issue.

Comment: You are likely getting this error because you don't have a data frame called `df`. R therefore assumes that you mean the function `df`. Is your own data perhaps called something else?

Comment: Maybe the last line, try `as.dendrogram()` with parentheses

Comment: Pretty challenging to help without your data - could you post your data using `dput(df)`?